# MeteorJS - How to prevent UnloggedIn Users from fetching database?

Tags: collections, meteor, fetch, publish

I'm populating an app using `MeteorJS`. Now there's one security issue that I need to fix is that in my app, an anonymous user can freely use this:

```
Meteor.users.find().fetch()
```

...in the console to get all the current users' information. And I also have the packages `insecure` & `autopublish` removed.

When I publish this users collection from the server, I did this:

```
Meteor.publish 'users basic info', ->
      Meteor.users.find {}, fields:
        "emails"  :1
        "profile" :1
```

But when any clients retrieve the data using `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`, they got more fields than what I restricted, for example `position`, `roles` etc...

Hope that you guys can help me with this. Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: shouldn't happen on the client, sure you aren't publishing it?

Comment: oh, just the current user?

Comment: I've just edited my question. It's not just the current user, any clients can retrieve data like that :(

Comment: certainly seems like it contradicts the documentation,  it says By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the current user with:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your publish function is returning all user documents to the client as you have an empty object as the query, which is why the client can see all user data.  You need to do the following (apologies, but I don't use CS):

```
Meteor.publish('users basic info', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        _id: this.userId
    }, {
    fields: {
        profile: 1,
        emails: 1
    });
});
```

Note that `this.userId` is a constant as opposed to a reactive variable, but the whole publish function reruns when the logged in user changes (including from null), so this should work fine.

Are the `position`, `roles`, etc. fields not subfields of `profile`?  If they're not and you have no other publish function for user data (and autopublish is removed), then it's really not clear why you can see those fields on the client.